# NSCache - discarding content

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage, nscache

I am using `NSCache` to store `UIImage` objects. I use `UITableView` to show the images and access the `NSCache` in the following manner:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.ImageTableCell, for: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell
    let brand = brands[indexPath.row]
    cell.centerLabel.text = brand.brand
    cell.leftImageView.image = nil

    if let image = self.brandLogosCache.object(forKey: brand.id as NSString) {
        cell.leftImageView.image = image
    } else if noLogosBrands.contains(brand.id) {
        return cell
    } else {
        ImagesManager.getBrandLogo(byLogoName: brand.logo!) { (error, imageData) in

            guard error == nil else {
                print("Could not get logo")
                return
            }

            if let image = UIImage(data: (imageData?.data)!) {
                self.brandLogosCache.setObject(image, forKey: brand.id as NSString)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.brandsTableView.reloadData()
                }
            } else {
                print("Could not form logo from incomming data")
                self.noLogosBrands.insert(brand.id)
            }

        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

I also have `extension` of `UIImage` that conforms to `NSDiscardableContent`. It is implemented just to have the conformance, because if I don't have it content gets discarded on app going to background:

```
extension UIImage : NSDiscardableContent {
    public func beginContentAccess() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    public func endContentAccess() {
        print("End content access")
    }

    public func discardContentIfPossible() {
        print("Discarding")
    }

    public func isContentDiscarded() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

}
```

The problem is I get content discarded all the time and it does not stop discarding, downloading images, saving them and discarding them again. I use NSCache at other places in the app and don't have this problem. What could be the reason?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to cache images in memory. A common pattern for this case is caching the resources/responses to disk. There are numerous libraries for this purpose ([Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) is one of them for example), you could use one of them or study their code and roll your own solution.

Comment: @Alladinian Thanks for the response. I also am thinking of using some external library if this doesn't get fixed, but NSCache also seemed like a good idea since it will remove objects when there is not enough memory.

Comment: The problem, in this case, is that mobile devices do not have large amounts of memory available to them and images are usually large in size (which means that the cache will be invalidated a lot under memory stress). In-memory caching could be useful for other things (like data structures) but for images, you should consider using disk caching. Btw, did you inspect the memory gauge while this is happening?

Comment: @Alladinian No, I didn't inspect it. I however made the change to Kingfisher and now it works well. Than you for the suggestion.